# How To Selectively Update Applications On Google Play?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates, customization

I would like to know how to update manually only apps that I want and not all apps at once when every other day they get updated again. How to checkmark only specific apps I want to manually update?

Answer (score 1):

You could check-mark for automatic updates those apps which you care about or just update each application individually.

Comment: Individually is not only time consuming, but frustrating because when update is performed, my smartphone becomes very sluggish that navigating back and forth to update specific apps manually merely become test of patience.

Comment: @Boris_yo, is setting specific apps to auto update is not an option for you?

Comment: I can set that option but the problem is when Android detects Wi-Fi access and decides to update all applications one after another in case they have not been updated long time. I have even heard story of this process crashing smartphone of somebody, making it fail to boot where the only way left to restore everything is with factory restore.

Comment: @Boris_yo, maybe you could disable auto update and perform "update all" when you do not use the phone. There is no other way than those mentioned above using Google Play app. If you're feeling good at scripting you could write your own updater which could download apks on PC and push them to device via adb.